# Do I need to register somewhere to use HTTPS?

Tags: apache, ssl, https

I'm trying to enable https://mysite.com on my Ubuntu 11.04/Apache 2
I followed several guides online, but I still cannot access https://mysite.com

The guides mentioned getting certificates from CA, does that mean I have to register somewhere?

Or, can I simply redirect all https traffic to http?

Comment: You need an SSL certificate from *somewhere*, doesn't matter where although self-signing has more trust and MITM problems than ones issued from a CA with a trust chain from the defaults installed in a browser. You also need to be making your apache listen on port 443 with that certificate although with the limited information you've posted I don't think it's possible to say any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You need to get and install an SSL certificate.

The whole point of SSL is that a trusted third party verifies your identity.

You are going to need to read up on SSL or hire someone.

Good luck